# Add element in product view error?

Tags: magento2

when i add mycustom in product view get error

> Call to a member function getName() on null in
>   **..\magento\catalog\view\frontend\templates\product\view\opengraph\general.phtml**
>   on line **13**

any help?

Comment: have you created block file?

Comment: what is "mycustom"?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()->getName(), 'name') ?>
```

**OR**

```
<?php echo $block->getProduct()->getName() ?>
```